# Angular universal alternative to queryselector

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-universal

All the plugins which are currently supporting angular 2.0 don't seem to support Angular Universal. It shows errors due to the direct `DOM` access. I want to alter the `DOM` access code in the angular 2 way. Can anyone suggest the angular 2 way for window, document,`queryselector()`, `querySelectorAll()`, `document.getElementsByTagname()`, `getElementsByClassName()`, etc.

Comment: Check out `@ViewChild` and `@HostBinding`, depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

At first, direct DOM access is discouraged in Angular2. You should prefer using directives like `*ngFor` and custom structural directives to update the DOM.

You can use one of the methods mentioned in [angular 2 / typescript : get hold of an element in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681) to get hold of an element and use what the [Renderer](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Renderer-class.html) provides to modify the DOM without breaking Universal.

For structural directives see also

- https://angular.io/docs/dart/latest/guide/structural-directives.html

Answer (score 0):

Direct Dom access is discouraged in Angular. Also, you can see comments about using elementRef. elementRef is also discouraged. For elementRef, Angular teams says:"Use this API as the last resort when direct access to DOM is needed.".

You can use renderer2 library. Use this library with elementRef together.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).